# Octopress Posix Error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, octopress

I'm trying to generate a blog with octopress. When I do rake deploy I get this error:

```
Could not find posix-spawn-0.3.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

bundle install:
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using RedCloth (4.2.9) 
Using posix-spawn (0.3.6) 
Using albino (1.3.3) 
Using blankslate (2.1.2.4) 
Using chunky_png (1.2.6) 
Using fast-stemmer (1.0.1) 
Using classifier (1.3.3) 
Using fssm (0.2.9) 
Using sass (3.2.1) 
Using compass (0.12.2) 
Using directory_watcher (1.4.1) 
Using ffi (1.0.11) 
Using haml (3.1.7) 
Using kramdown (0.13.8) 
Using liquid (2.3.0) 
Using syntax (1.0.0) 
Using maruku (0.6.0) 
Using jekyll (0.11.2) 
Using rubypython (0.5.3) 
Using pygments.rb (0.2.13) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-protection (1.2.0) 
Using rb-fsevent (0.9.1) 
Using rdiscount (1.6.8) 
Using rubypants (0.2.0) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sinatra (1.3.3) 
Using stringex (1.4.0) 
Using bundler (1.1.5) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is     
installed.
```

I have the right version of posix-spawn installed, so I'm not sure how to fix this error. I even recompiled it with my package manager, and still get the same error.

-- Gemfile

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

group :development do
  gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  gem 'rack', '~> 1.4.1'
  gem 'jekyll', '~> 0.11.2'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  gem 'rdiscount', '~> 1.6.8'
  gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.2.12'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.9'
  gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.6'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.1'
  gem 'rubypants', '~> 0.2.0'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'stringex', '~> 1.4.0'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  gem 'liquid', '~> 2.3.0'
end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.3.2'
```

Comment: added. Its a standard octpress install on arch linux

Comment: posix-spawn-0.3.6.gem is not being found on rubygems or your local - so you need to find if it's a network break, or the local file is no accessible as you think.